# Can I avoid deserializing JSON Jackson http response body twice if I want to set READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL?

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

> I am deserializing a JSON http response and reading it into a Java object.

My first solution was:

```
javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = ...
MyClass obj = response.readEntity(MyClass.class);
```

I want to read unknown enum values of enum members in MyClass as null and not throw an exception, so I modified the above to:

```
String str = response.readEntity(String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL, true);
MyClass obj = mapper.readValue(string, Class<MyClass>);
```

Does anyone know how I could avoid the double deserialization here i.e. instead of Response -> String -> Class, just do Response -> Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this is to register an ObjectMapperContextResolver with the client

```
private final ObjectMapperContextResolver OBJECT_MAPPER_CONTEXT_RESOLVER = new ObjectMapperContextResolver();

javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ...
javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget target = client.target("..."); 
client.register(OBJECT_MAPPER_CONTEXT_RESOLVER).target("...");

javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = target.path("...").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
MyClass obj = response.readEntity(MyClass.class);
```